# How to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x+t) - f(x)|dx \to 0$ as $t\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(-\infty, +\infty)$ and $g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x+t) - f(x)|dx$. How to show that $\lim_{t\to0}g(t) = 0$? Originally I thought that we need to use [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). However, it is not necessary that such $h(x)$ exists that $|f(x + t_n)| < h(x)$.

I have this question from reading the proof of approximating $f$ with a continuous function. So we cannot use this fact!
Thank you.

Comment: Generally, such a $h$ doesn't exist. Showing $\lim_{t\to 0} g(t) = 0$ is easy if $f$ is continuous with compact support. The general case follows by approximation.

Comment: $f$ is not necessary continuous. What type of approximations do we need in the general case?

Comment: You approximate $f \in L^1$ by continuous functions with compact support. Given $f \in L^1$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $f_{\varepsilon} \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\lVert f - f_{\varepsilon}\rVert_{L^1} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: This what I actually need to prove :-). I need to prove this results that we can approximate $f$ with a continuous function. And In the proof, this is the last step.

Comment: Thank you, that is my mistake  that I thought that the Donimated theorem is the tool to go. I am going to edit the question.

Comment: To do that approximation: You know simple functions are dense, so you need only approximate $\chi_E$ by a continuous function with compact support. There exist compact $K$ and open $V$ with $K\subset E\subset V$ and $m(V\setminus K)<\epsilon$...

Comment: Where did you read that proof? Online somewhere, in a book by some smart guy or what? It's possible that the author was simply overlooking a circularity in the argument. I conjecture that the proof of approximation is by showing that $f*\phi_h\to f$, where $\phi_h$ is an approximate identity. [continued]

Comment: [continued] I've been writing a little something on basic real analysis - I was going to use that argument to show that $L^1$ functions could be approximated  by continuous functions, I realized that we needed to know that $\int|f(x-t)-f(x)|dx\to0$, I thought about that for some time and didn't see a way to do it without _first_ showing $f$ could be approximated be continuous functions. I finally gave up and used another argument to show the approximation. So: Where did you read this proof? How reputable a source?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, the book is Smoothing and Approximation of Functions by Harold Shapiro

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, It is the very first example in the book. The author shows that we can approximate $f$ with a smooth function convolution, exactly as you mention. But in the end of the proof, they use the fact I asked question about.

Comment: Well that's certainly a reputable source. It's still possible that he overlooked the circularity. And of course it's also quite possible that I just don't see how to do it. But I did think about it some a few months ago, and came up empty. (Not that that proves anything except that if there's a good answer you'll have to get it from someone else...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, FYI I found a hint in the book. The way to go is to approximate $f$ using step functions.

Comment: Assuming you really mean step function, that is a linear combination of characteristic functions of _intervals_, then yes that would do it. But that's a little wacky, because once we know that we can approximate $f$ by a step function it's completely utterly trivial to approximate $f$ by a continuous function! Absolutely nothing at all; it's _obvious_ that there is a continuous function $\phi$ so $||\phi-\chi_{[a,b]}||_1<\epsilon$. Step function to continuous function is _so_ trivial that in my universe if we have step functions we _do_ have continuous functions.

Comment: To put it another way, what you're suggesting sounds like we prove $f$ can be approximated by continuous functions, deduce that $||f-\tau_hf||_1\to0$ (where $\tau_h$ is translation) and then pretend we haven't shown we can approximate by continuous functions so we can give another proof of that...